# How can I get out of this "➜ ~" state in my mac terminal and revert to the normal terminal state?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-monterey

I tried making a git commit and push from my VS Code application. Immediately after making the commit and push, I realized that my mac terminal was in a different state. [This is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkkgy.png) Can someone help me revert back to my original mac terminal? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Note that modern macOS sets your shell to zsh (not bash or tcsh) by default. Prompts are produced *by* your shell, using rules that are specific *to* your shell, so which shell you've chosen is the first question you must address. After that, the next question is *are you using someone's prompt package for that shell* and then (if so) *whose / which*. This has little if anything to do with Git, though there are numerous prompt packages that will show some Git state *in* the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like the oh-my-zsh *robbyrussell* prompt to me.

Maybe VS Code changed your default shell (which was *bash* I suppose).

Try [changing the default shell](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/change-the-default-shell-trml113/mac) back to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: My default shell was zsh and that hasn't changed.